# Bootstrap Material Design(4.1.1)'s bmd-label-floating not working well with autofocus attribute

Tags: javascript, focus, material-design, bootstrap-4, autofocus

## 1. On page load

The autofocus attribute doesn't trigger the Bootstrap-JavaScript to add the `is-focused` class to the corresponding `(bmd-)form-group`.

[image: 1]

```
<fieldset class="form-group bmd-form-group">
    <label for="usernameControl" class="bmd-label-floating">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-light" required="" id="usernameControl" name="username" autofocus="">
</fieldset>
```

## 2. After some typing

When typing something in the field, the label goes up because `is-filled` gets added, but the focus is still not recognized.

[image: 2]

```
<fieldset class="form-group bmd-form-group is-filled">
    <label for="usernameControl" class="bmd-label-floating">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-light" required="" id="usernameControl" name="username" autofocus="">
</fieldset>
```

## 3. After reselecting (desirable output)

Deselecting the text-input (with mouseclicks or the tab-key) and then selecting it again is the only way to get the `is-focused` class (and therefore making it look like it should).

[image: 3]

```
<fieldset class="form-group bmd-form-group is-filled is-focused">
    <label for="usernameControl" class="bmd-label-floating">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-light" required="" id="usernameControl" name="username" autofocus="">
</fieldset>
```

## Question

Is there any fix or workaround to this problem?

Bootstrap Material Design used: https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ (Version 4.1.1)

## Source/input html:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="usernameControl" class="bmd-label-floating">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-light" required="" id="usernameControl" name="username" autofocus="">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: Hardcoding the `is-focused` class to the corresponding `(bmd-)form-group` of the autofocused item works.

```
<fieldset class="form-group is-focused">
    <label for="usernameControl" class="bmd-label-floating">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-light" required="" id="usernameControl" name="username" autofocus="">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script> $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign({}); </script>
```

add this to your website if you're using https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design This will fix forms etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are using like below code it's fine (bmd-)form-group.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-light" id="usernameControl" name="username">
```

If you are using property like autofocus,required,readonly ect.. i:

autofocus,
 required,
 readonly
and alike, it wouldn't work, so you have to add a new custom class to work this scenario.